# Padding for all screens

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to give padding once for all screens? For example somehow in theme?
I have one the same padding for all screen, which later I am maybe gonna change, it would be very efficient if I could change only one value for all views

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own widget that includes a Scaffold and a Padding and takes a child.